# How to get a sub-vale from a multi-dimensional array with only 1 sub-value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$gpph_array=
    Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 83 [GPPH] => 18.80 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [product_id] => 93 [GPPH] => 20.55 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [product_id] => 94 [GPPH] => 30.75 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [product_id] => 109 [GPPH] => 5.60 ) 
    )
```

Lets say I have a product_id of 109 how do I extract only the associated GPPH value of 5.60 with php?

```
<?php 
echo '[GPPH] where [product_id)=>109';
?>
```

I've read many post dealing with multidimensional arrays but only seen people loop through results. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this will involve a loop. Have you tried something?

Comment: What's wrong with loops?

Comment: Why not restructure your array to have the `product_id` as the key, and the `GPPH` as the value, eliminating the need for a multidimensional array entirely. Then, you could simply use `$gpph_array[$product_id]` to acquire the corresponding GPPH.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Vulcan that is awesome foresight for what I was trying to accomplish.

I was using this method to create my array:

```
$gpph_array=array();
  while($grow=mysql_fetch_assoc($gquery)) {
  $gpph_array[] = $grow;
    }
```

which was creating the multi-dimensial array,
like

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [product_id] => 83 [GPPH] => 18.80 ) 
[1] => Array ( [product_id] => 93 [GPPH] => 20.55 ) 
[2] => Array ( [product_id] => 94 [GPPH] => 30.75 ) 
[3] => Array ( [product_id] => 109 [GPPH] => 5.60 ) 
)
```

by changing to

```
$gpph_array=array();
   while($grow=mysql_fetch_assoc($gquery)) {
   $gpph_array[$grow['product_id']]=$grow['GPPH']; 
            }
```

I got a single array which is much easier to pluck values from since I will know the product id.

```
Array ( [83] => 18.80 [93] => 20.55 [94] => 30.75 [109] => 5.60)
```

Great thinking Vulcan

Comment: You should start using PDO / mysqli. mysql_ is being deprecated.

Comment: Glad to have helped. You should mark your own answer as accepted for the benefit of future visitors.